# Do not render footer for new and edit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I don't want the footer to render for edit or new for about five controllers.

Something like `<%= render 'layouts/footer'`**, except: [:new, :edit**] `%>` in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

I think I see ways to do it by changing each controller, but this would cover at least 5 tables in my case.

Or can I know the action rendering and the could do an if then else in the `_footer.html.erb`.

This seems like it would be common, so Rails must have an easy way to do it.

Comment: all new and edit, or jsut for a certain controller?

Comment: All controllers

Comment: Just have a double-check, you want to remove the footer in new and edit for five controllers or all controllers in your rails app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' unless ["new", "edit"].include?(action_name) %>
```

In this long run though there are better techniques for dynamic chunks in your layout like using the [captures helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) and [named yields](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).

Comment: Thank you that does it. And also for pointing out more robust approaches.